# does any other desktop have searching within file menus?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

I'm increasingly thinking of moving away from the default unity desktop, as it seems to be semi-mothballed and I really like the most recent gnome 3 releases on my arch machine. However, there is one feature of unity that I'm really going to miss: being able to tap Alt and search within file menus. This makes gimp and libreoffice feel way less like the two-decade accumulation of features that they are, and significantly improves usability for these sorts of programs. Does anyone know of anything comparable for KDE5 or Gnome 3? Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I never realized this existed.  Finally, after N years someone shows me a feature in Unity that is helpful.

Comment: Ha! You're welcome! Like I said, it's really only useful for programs that have somewhat outdated/overwhelming UX (infinite drop-down menus), but since that describes most non-Vala Linux office software, it is pretty nice.